# Rails 4 iterate Dates Within a .times do

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, iteration

I am trying to run `number_of_days.times do` to create a table, and in the first column I need to iterate through dates. I am trying to add `+ 1.day` for each `.times do` so that each row of the table has the next date. I am blanking on why my counter isn't working inside the `.times do` and what I should do about it. Here is my code:

`@day_count` is the number of days from a starting date to today, which I have confirmed is working to return the correct number integer and in fact is running through my `times do` correctly because it creates the correct number of table rows.

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <th><strong>Date</strong></th>
  <th><strong>Total Entries</strong></th>
  <th><strong>New Entries</strong></th>
  <th><strong>New Form Entries</strong></th>
  <th><strong>New Image Entries</strong></th>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <% count = -1 %>
  <% @day_count.times do %>
  <tr>
   <% count.to_i + 1 %>
    <td><%= @start_date + count.day %></td>
    <td> test </td>
    <td> test </td>
    <td> test </td>
    <td> test </td>
   </tr>
  <% end %>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

each`@start_date + count.day` produces the same date. I know I am missing something very simple here... thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you're incrementing the `count` variable each time the loop is iterated.

Try adding `count += 1` somewhere in there.

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <th><strong>Date</strong></th>
  <th><strong>Total Entries</strong></th>
  <th><strong>New Entries</strong></th>
  <th><strong>New Form Entries</strong></th>
  <th><strong>New Image Entries</strong></th>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <% count = 0 %>
  <% @day_count.times do %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= @start_date + count.day %></td>
    <% count += 1 %>
    <td> test </td>
    <td> test </td>
    <td> test </td>
    <td> test </td>
   </tr>
  <% end %>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! Its crazy the things you forget. That worked.

Comment: Totally been there :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you wouldn't:

```
(1..@day_count).each do |count|
  ...
```

or

```
(@start_date..Date.today).each do |day|
  ...
```